# Bootstrap3 container with responsive image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am new to BS3 and i'm trying to use a responsive image with the img-responsive class that spans the width of the container across all screen sizes and devices. What I have so far works apart from screen break points between 768px and 992px where the image doesn't retain its 100% width. I'm not quite sure where I am going wrong. plus I can not seem to remove  left/right padding so it covers the complete width of the container. Ive tried using Jumbatron with no success.

I simply have an image in my outer container like so: -

```
  <div class="container-fluid wrapper">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="../images/home/hands-and-key.jpg" alt=""/> 
  </div>
```

Do I need to use rows and column classes for this?

Comment: wrap the img in a row then column

Comment: Thanks SuncoastOwner. the only problem I now have is how to remove the padding for small devices (smartphones) so the image spans the width of the viewport. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Not to worry!! Ive just realised its similar to BS2 and have achieved it with the appropriate media query and removing margin and padding from the container.